# zsh doesn't show signal/error name for a failed C executable when run from a script

Tags: c, shell, zsh

I just found that my zsh don't alert me when there's a runtime error.
Can anyone help me?

```
int main(void) {
    int a = 1;
    int b = 0;
    int c = a/b;
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled it and wrote a script to run it,

```
./a.out
```

I then entered `zsh a.sh`. It finished without any error.

But when I run it with the command line `./a.out` it showed:
`zsh: floating point exception  ./a.out`

I'm using MacOS Monterey 12.2.1 and my zsh is `zsh 5.8 (x86_64-apple-darwin21.0)`.

Really thanks!

I now understand that interactive and non-interactive shells have many different behaviors but I still don't know if there's a way zsh can tell me the error. (especially when the script is in .zshrc) The error message is kind of important.

Comment: Interactive and non-interactive shells have many different behaviors.

Comment: I understand, now I'm wondering how to enable zsh to informe me when there's an error. If I use sh or bash, they will tell me the floating point exception. @Barmar

Comment: Technically, it *did* exit with an error (the exit status is non-zero), but for some reason the error message is being suppressed.

Comment: You can explicitly run an interactive shell with `zsh -i a.sh` and see the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you see is specific to the interactive shell, which detects that your program exit with a floating-point exception and reports it. It's not clear how to make a non-interactive shell report the error similarly, but it would be better to do such error-checking yourself. For example,

```
./a.out
case $? in
  0) print "Success" ;;
  *) print "Error: $?" ;;
esac
```

Comment: Might be worth propagating the error out, instead of having the wrapper always exit with success even when the thing being wrapped failed.

Comment: I was only pointing out that the exit status should be explicitly examined, rather than assuming the shell will do something. with it. The exception doesn't cause the script itself to exit.